# How to get info from json using a variable

Tags: javascript, html, json

So I'm trying to get data from a JSON and I declared a variable and want to use the thing from that variable to get info from the JSON I'm trying to do this but I don't know what the problem is

```js
let e = "KA8AL9AE";
let codes = '{"T9R3P5YE": "10", "8HAW69VC": "20"}'
codes = JSON.parse(codes)
console.log(codes.e)
```

I've tried doing

```js
let e = "KA8AL9AE";
let codes = '{"T9R3P5YE": "10", "8HAW69VC": "20"}'
codes = JSON.parse(codes)
console.log(`${codes. + e}`)
```

But it didn't work, Is there a way to do this?

Comment: have you tried codes[e]?

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the new key like:
`codes[e]`

Comment: Ah, Thank you That worked!